# High charts is not showing values properly on line chart

Tags: debugging, highcharts, scale, linechart

```
trying to create highcharts as in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o2sgjtr1/1/
```

Where the line chart value 2 and 4 but the line still shows zero value not sure what should the configure to get the proper scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `yAxis.type` to `logarithimic` is the best way to deal with your problem. Logarithmic axes can be useful when dealing with data with spikes or large value gaps, as they allow variance in the smaller values to remain visible.

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ar7z1pvt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

Comment: How to set min y axis value to 0   min:0 property not working please let me know how to set the property

Comment: Logarithms of negative numbers are not defined in real numbers. The natural logarithm function ln(x) is defined only for x>0. So the natural logarithm of a negative number is undefined. But there is a little trick in Highcharts, you can use some custom options and use custom plugin to wrap some core functions to achieve working negative values in logarithmic type.


**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9hjLyxq7/

Comment: can u please check this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094510/high-stocks-charts-displays-fewer-values-even-though-plot-value-exists