# High stocks charts displays fewer values even though plot value exists

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, icons, zooming

```
I have combination chart as displayed in the fiddle using highcharts
https://jsfiddle.net/u1p2ebk0/3/
```

but while displaying September month plots  are not showing the custom icons on the chart really not sure why is this behavior and also when i click no  **1m** zoom  custom icons are showing but on load also it should show the icons not sure what i am missing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All flags are not displayed because there is no place for them all. When you set `series.flags.allowOverlapX` property to `true`, all flags will be shown but they will overlap each other. You can try to reduce their size or alternatively modify the amount of setting data depending on rangeSelector selection or chart size.

Let me know in case of any implementation issues.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rk95uL10/

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.allowOverlapX